# How to refresh a Fragment and an Activity in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity, fragment

I have made a Login form and got the user details into a Sqlite database. In the HomeFragment extends fragment class I have a Textview where I want to set the user's name. I don't get the name immediately after logging in, but when I go to another activities and then go to HomeFragment the textview is set to the user's name. Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Here is my code.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
public HomeFragment(){}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     Databasehandler db=new Databasehandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
     final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
     TextView names=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
     HashMap<String, String> c=db.getAddedContacts();
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+c, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     names.setText(""+c.get("userlogin"));
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the login code?

Comment: Its actually a facebook login code. and i have inserted that data into sqlite database. The names are actually getting inserted into the database.

Comment: Can you suggest how can i refresh the fragment class

Comment: Call this Databasehandler db=new Databasehandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext()); after your view inflated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an asynctask for the login and put the setText of TextView in the post method. And in the pre method put progress bar and make it visible and hide it in the post method , For the text not to show immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Facebook's graph API. In that case you get a callback that provides a GraphUser object when the login is complete. In that callback, call `textView.setText(graphUser.getName());` to refresh the username `TextView`.